# How to return nested class pointer from method?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have two classes: `Database` and `Node` as a nested class, is it possible to have a method of `Node` that will return a `Node*`?

I tried to set the method `nextNode` return type as `Node*` but I get a compilation error: `'Node' does not name a type`

Databse.h

```
class Database
{
    public:
        Database();
        Database& operator+=(const Client&);
        ~Database();
    private:
        class Node //node as nested class
        {
            public:
            Node(); //ctor
            void setHead(Client*&); //add head node
            Node* nextNode(Node*&); //return new node from the end of he list
            private:
            Client* data; //holds pointer to Client object
            Node* next; //holds pointer to next node in list
        };

        Node *head; //holds the head node
};
```

`nextNode` method declaration in Databse.cpp:

```
Node* Database::Node::nextNode(Node*& start)
{
....
....
    return current->next;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Node` is nested in `Database`, so you need the scope for the return type:

```
DataBase::Node* Database::Node::nextNode(Node*& start)
^^^^^^^^^^
```

The parameter is already in scope, so you may leave it as is.

Comment: Thanks!
Can you direct me to some good documentation about nested classes?

Comment: @Medvednic I would go through some of the [books in this list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to juanchopanza's answer, C++11's trailing return type allows you to declare it in-scope :

```
auto Database::Node::nextNode(Node*& start) -> Node* {
    // ...
}
```